# Converting scalar ODE to coupled system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I'm currently battling the following problem:
\begin{align}
u^{(iv)} (x) &= f(x)\quad\text{on }(0,1)\\
u(0) = u'(0) &= 0\\
u''(1) = u'''(1) &= 0
\end{align}
which is, as I've understood, a beam equation for a cantilevered beam.
I am given the hint to define a new variable $p:=u''$ and to reformulate
the first equation  as a coupled system of second order ODEs.

Now the first idea was to just use the substitution, thus arriving at:
\begin{align*}
p(x) &= u''(x) \\
p'' (x) &= f(x)\\
u(0) = u'(0) &= 0\\
p(1) = p'(1) &= 0
\end{align*}
where in the first two equations $x\in(0,1)$ is understood. This however, is not what we're looking for.
Furthermore using the fundamental theorem of calculus I can gain
\begin{align*}
u'(x) &= u'(0) + \int_0^x u''(s)ds = \int_0^x p(s)ds\\
u(x) &= u(0) + \int_0^x u'(s)ds = \int_0^x u'(s)ds\\
&= \int_0^x \int_0^s p(y)dy ds\quad .
\end{align*}

I would like to ask for a hint (and hopefully not one applied with a sledgehammer)
where I'm going in the wrong direction.

N.B.
The new variable looks awfully like a Legendre transform, but there I again don't see where I
should go.

Comment: I edited your post. PDE involves partial derivatives. What you are looking at is a system of ODEs, not of PDEs.

Comment: I think I'll have to disagree. The exercise states explicitly to transform the differential equation into a "coupled partial differential equation of second order" for $u$ and $p$. The goal is (in the second part) to reformulate the resulting equation using weak derivatives (this is a course in numerics of PDEs - FEM). The guy who makes the problems generally puts much effort into stating them correctly - so I kinda trust the problem statement.

Comment: "The guy who makes the problems" is simply wrong or careless here. (Anyone can have a "moment".) You may make the case that an ODE is a PDE with only one independent variable, but people would look at you funny for saying that.

Comment: You're right. I've asked the TA and he admitted that the problem was unfortunately phrased and that he meant at least what I've written as the second set of equations in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p(1)=p'(1)=0$, one can use the trick you applied to $u$ on $(0,x)$, but on $(y,1)$ for $p$. This yields $$p(y)=\int_y^1\int_z^1f(t)\mathrm dt\mathrm dz,$$ hence $$u(x)=\int_0^x\mathrm ds\int_0^s\mathrm dy\int_y^1\mathrm dz\int_z^1f(t)\mathrm dt,$$ and the task is to transform this into a single integral. An approach which is less error-prone than some others, is to use indicator functions, that is, to rewrite $u(x)$ as $$u(x)=\int_{[0,1]^4}f(t)\mathbf 1_{y\lt s\lt x}\mathbf 1_{y\lt z\lt t}\mathrm ds\mathrm dy\mathrm dz\mathrm dt=\int_0^1f(t)g_x(t)\mathrm dt,$$ where, for every $t$ and $x$ in $[0,1]$, $$g_x(t)=\int_{[0,1]^3}\mathbf 1_{y\lt s\lt x}\mathbf 1_{y\lt z\lt t}\mathrm ds\mathrm dy\mathrm dz=\int_0^x\int_0^t\min(s,z)\mathrm dz\mathrm ds.$$ 
For every $(t,s)$ such that $u=\min(s,t)$, $$\int_0^t\min(s,z)\mathrm dz=\int_0^uz\mathrm dz+\int_u^ts\mathrm dz=\tfrac12u^2+s(t-u),$$ hence $$g_x(t)=\int_0^x\left(\tfrac12\min(s,t)^2+s(t-\min(s,t))\right)\mathrm ds,$$ that is, considering $v=\min(x,t)$, $$g_x(t)=\int_0^v\left(\tfrac12s^2+s(t-s)\right)\mathrm ds+\int_v^x\left(\tfrac12t^2+s(t-t)\right)\mathrm ds=\int_0^v\left(st-\tfrac12s^2\right)\mathrm ds+\tfrac12t^2\int_v^x\mathrm ds,$$
or, equivalently, $$g_x(t)=\tfrac12tv^2-\tfrac16v^3+\tfrac12t^2(x-v)=\tfrac12txv-\tfrac16v^3.$$ Finally, for every $x$ in $[0,1]$,

> $$u(x)=\tfrac12x\int_0^xt^2f(t)\mathrm dt-\tfrac16\int_0^xt^3f(t)\mathrm dt+\tfrac12x^2\int_x^1tf(t)\mathrm dt-\tfrac16x^3\int_x^1f(t)\mathrm dt.$$